# Why is the TextBox always null on the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the designer.cs file, there is this line:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtStartDate;
```

And in my .aspx file, I have this line:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtStartDate" />
```

But whenever I try to access the text box, like so:

```
sqlCMDErrorLog.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartDate", txtStartDate.Text));
```

It's always null. Why is this?

Comment: I'm assuming there is also a line in the designer similar to `txtStartDate = new TextBox();` or something?

Comment: I think you need to use [FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Does the `TextBox` exist inside another control?

Comment: Where are you calling the sqlCMDErrorLog line from? In what context?

Comment: @DavidG: It's in the DOM.  To get a reference to it in CodeBehind, you have to use FindControl.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not sure you're correct here. You only need to use FindControl when the control is inside another, such as a Repeater or Grid.

Comment: We're going to need to see more code.  Can you paste your ASPX page and your entire CodeBehind method?